# SQL to select duplicate codes filtering by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following table:

```
id  name                   code                    date
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1   name1                  c01                     10/01/2017
2   name1                  c02                     10/05/2017
3   name2                  c01                     02/04/2017
4   name2                  c02                     02/07/2017
5   name2                  c03                     02/15/2017
6   name2                  c02                     02/20/2017
7   name2                  c04                     03/01/2017
8   name3                  c01                     04/18/2017
9   name3                  c02                     04/29/2017
10  name3                  c01                     05/03/2017
```

I need to select the names that contains duplicate codes that are in different months. Name1 does not contains duplicate codes, Name2 contains duplicate code c02 but both codes are on February so it should not appear but Name3 contains duplicate code c01 that have different months April and May so it should appear.

```
name                   
-----
name3
```

I am using the following select to get the names that have duplicate codes but not sure how to validate if they are in different months:

```
select name, code, count(*) from table having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . .

```
select distinct name
from t
group by name, code
having year(min(date)) <> year(max(date)) or
       month(min(date)) <> month(max(date));
```

This is one of the very, very few cases where using `select distinct` makes sense with `group by`.  Note that if you wanted the `code` as well, you could do `select name, code`.

Also, the `having` could be changed to:

```
having datediff(month, min(date), max(date)) <> 0
```

This will formally filter out any rows that are in different calendar months.  Someone less experienced might be confused, thinking that 2017-01-31 and '2017-02-01 are not a month apart (which they are according to `datediff()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by grouping each name for each code in each month. And then select those entries who has count greater than 1. This will have all names which has more than code repeated. Again group the results based on month to find how many names are repeated for the same code in same month. Result only the codes which has one code for a month

```
SELECT name, code, month(your_date), count(*)
  FROM yourtable y,
      (SELECT name, code,count(*)
         FROM yourtable
      GROUP BY NAME, CODE
       HAVING count(*) >2) x
WHERE x.name = y.name and x.code = y.code
GROUP BY name, code
HAVING count(*) = 1
```